# dig to www got no answer with bind

Tags: 14.04, dns, bind

I'm trying to set up a domain. It works for vumila.com, but not with www.vumila.com. Here are my files:

db.vumila.com:

```
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     ns1.vumila.com. admin.vumila.com. (
                          2015011601        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.vumila.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.vumila.com.


vumila.com.    IN      MX      10      mail.vumila.com.
vumila.com.    IN      A       216.172.176.81
ns1                     IN      A       216.172.176.82
ns2                     IN      A       216.172.176.81
www.vumila.com.                     IN      CNAME       vumila.com.
mail                    IN      A       216.172.176.82
ftp                     IN      CNAME   vumila.com.
```

db.216.172.176:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for 176.172.216.in-addr.arpa
;
$TTL    604800
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.      IN      SOA     ns1.vumila.com. admin.vumila.com. (
                          2015011601         ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns1.vumila.com.
176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      ns2.vumila.com.

82.176.172.216.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR     vumila.com.
```

when i dig www.vumila.com i got this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> www.vumila.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8352
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.vumila.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
vumila.com.     505 IN  SOA ns1.launchpad.com. anb.hotmail.com. 2014122502 7200 7200 172800 38400

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 15 18:48:19 CST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but two questions. In summary, either your local configuration might be wrong, or you might be configuring the wrong machine alltogether

### Config file wrong?

I can't test this right now, but in your db.vumila.com you have `www.vumila.com.`, why not just `www`?

### Wrong machine?

Where are you changing the bind configuration? Is that server actually the responsible DNS server for the domain? It looks like ns1.launchpad.com would hold the www.vumila.com entry, that is probably not your server, right?

Comment: I tried both, and no results

Comment: Where are you changing the bind configuration? Is that server actually the responsible DNS server for the domain? It looks like ns1.launchpad.com would hold the www.vumila.com entry, that is probably not your server, right?

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps ironically) a domain file isn't supposed to contain the domain name. You set that higher up. A domain file will just have something like:

```
@          A      <IP address>
```

`@` is a wildcard for all (and no) subdomain so covers `www.domain.ext` and `domain.ext`

---

That said, there are few good reasons for hosting your own DNS. It's a target for hacking and DDoS reflection attacks so let somebody else do it. They'll do a better job and most have a webui to let you do it through your browser (rather than fighting an ancient crufty syntax). Places to look:

- Your registrar almost certainly has a good, massively redundant DNS infrastructure.
- Your web host probably has one too.
- And there are plenty of free (and paid) DNS services (eg [ZoneEdit](https://www.zoneedit.com/)) out there too.